# [objective-c]Take screen capture without cursor

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

For screen capture i use CGDisplayCreateImage. But in output image i see cursor. How i can take screen capture without cursor?

```
CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImage(kCGDirectMainDisplay);
```

This bug i see on Siera. On El capitan, i can enable or disable cursor use

kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the mouse cursor using [`CGDisplayHideCursor()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456534-cgdisplayhidecursor?language=objc). Of course you have to turn it on after capturing the display.

```
CGDisplayHideCursor(kCGDirectMainDisplay);
CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImage(kCGDirectMainDisplay);
CGDisplayShowCursor(kCGDirectMainDisplay);
```

Comment: Nope, in outpus screen i see cursor too )))

Comment: *In most cases, the caller must be the foreground application to affect the cursor.*  Is your App the foreground app?

Comment: If i dow

 

     CGDisplayHideCursor(kCGDirectMainDisplay);

     CGDisplayShowCursor(kCGDirectMainDisplay);

 

 

cursor will be flick. I`m capture screen 20 times in second. For capture screen i use

 
CGDisplayStreamCreate, set property kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor to false, and for get image use CGDisplayCreateImage. On El Capitan i get correct image without cursor. But on Siera, image allways with cursor.

Comment: @АнтонМихайлов did you manage to hide the cursor for CGDisplayStream using the kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor key on newer MacOS versions? I'm struggling to make it work in Swift - the cursor is there even if I set the flag to false

Comment: On Catalina kCGDisplayStreamShowCursor work is fine. This bug on Siera and Capitan